# Iterate through every excel file in one directory, convert individual sheets to CSV files

Tags: ruby, excel, csv

I'be been trying to write a bit of code that iterates through every excel file in one directory, and convert excel workbooks to individual sheets to CSV files. I'm quite new to both ruby and coding in general, so I've no idea if my solution is the best method. The problem I am having is the Dir.foreach doesn't seem to iterate correctly, instead returning "C:\gernericfolder\." This then causes the next win32ole code block a whole tonne of problems.

This is my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'iconv'
require 'win32ole'
require 'csv'
require 'roo'

begin
  puts("=================================================================================================================================")

  inputFolder = ARGV[0]
  outputFolder = ARGV[1]

  #Check if the file actually exists + UI Feedback
  if File.exists?(inputFolder) == false 
    puts("IGM:  DIRECTORY NOT FOUND.  Please check your path exists\n")
    Process.exit
  end

  Dir.foreach(inputFolder) { |nextFile|
    #Form the file path and open the file
    filePath = "#{inputFolder}\\#{nextFile}"
    puts("Next file = #{filePath}")

    xl = WIN32OLE.new('excel.application')
    book = xl.workbooks.open(filePath)
    xl.displayalerts = false
  end
end
```

Comment: It is hard to answer to "a whole tonne of problems", you should provide an actual stack trace (you may add it to your question). This *is* StackOverflow after all, so you should provide us with accurate information about your problem. P.S.: Please do provide the actual call of your script too (i.e. the complete command line).

Answer (score 1):

I've been getting one showstopper problem using EXCEL via win32ole with Ruby 1.9.3/WATIR Classic: I get an intermittent Security error - "Watir::Exception::FrameAccessDeniedException IE will not allow access to this frame for security reasons. You can work around this with browser.goto(frame.src)".

The control this often happens with, but not all the time, is a IFRAME JavaScript link under Internet Explorer 10. I found a work-around that eliminates the issue if I assign the page URL to the list of trusted sites. But because I had to uncheck the HTTPS: checkbox to allow HTTP: URLs, it is unacceptable security practices and I got my wrist virtually slapped.

Our architect says it should be consistent if it's really a Security error. He ran tests which convinced him that the issue is not with Security but rather with using EXCEL and some related process: He eliminated EXCEL, which I was using to pass different UserIDs and Passwords to the Watir script. Once he eliminated EXCEL from the picture, the error no longer happened. Here's how he did it: He ran the first iteration of the script over and over in a batch file that clicked on the frame/link in question the same number of times that the EXCEL table was driving it, and the problem no longer happened. Now I have to use EXCEL some other way beside the win32ole, or go to using .CSV files, which I don't really look forward to because I lose track of how many commas I'm counting.

One solution to your problem, however primitive, is to manually copy and paste the EXCEL data into the .CSV tables.

Another possibility is a suggestion from a colleague:  Use EXCEL via the "Ruby Gem Spreadsheet".  She is using that and has not had any issues, although I'm pretty sure she isn't using IFRAMES with JavaScript hyperlinks on web pages written in .NET C#.  Her app is written in JAVA. But I will look into that option.

Answer (score 0):

`Dir.foreach` iterates through directory entries, not exactly files. That means, it returns such entries as `.` (this directory) and `..` (parent directory) among others. That's what you get: your `nextFile` is `.`.

The best way to quickly solve is is probably to switch from `Dir.foreach` to `Dir.glob` or `Dir[]`. That is, replace

```
Dir.foreach(inputFolder) { |nextFile|
  #Form the file path and open the file
  filePath = "#{inputFolder}\\#{nextFile}"
  puts("Next file = #{filePath}")
```

with

```
Dir.glob(inputFolder+'\**') { |filePath|
  puts("Next file = #{filePath}")
```